# Explain `fstab` swap syntax

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, mount, swap

Disk sda is SSD, while sdb is a conventional hard drive.

```
# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition       8387580 4333320 -1
/dev/sdb7                               partition       4194300 0       -2
/dev/sdb8                               partition       4194296 0       -3
/dev/sdb9                               partition       4194296 0       -4
/dev/sdb10                              partition       4194300 0       -5
# _
```

I think this situation (in which most priorized is sda1) is in force since the swapping off of all sbd$NUMBER.

```
# cat /etc/fstab
[...]
/dev/sda1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb7 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb8 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb9 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb10 none swap sw 0 0
[...]
# _
```

I am not sure what will be the priorities when I get to reboot this.

**What do `none swap sw 0 0` mean in `/etc/fstab`?**

**Can I tweak those to priorize sda1 as first swap?**

Do ordering of swap lines in `/etc/fstab` affect priority of *equal* (same `none swap sw 0 0` thing) swap lines?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the priority in `fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2   none    swap    sw,pri=30    0  0
/dev/sdb2   none    swap    sw,pri=20    0  0
/dev/sdc2   none    swap    sw,pri=10    0  0
```

By default, each added swapspace will be given a priority -1, -2, -3... The highest priority will get used first.  Above, the system would use `/dev/sda2` first, then `/dev/sdb2`, then `/dev/sdc2`.

If more than one swap has the same priority, the swap spaces will be used in parallel.

Comment: Nice, I'll be doing some testing whenever I can reboot the host, then eventually accept. About multiple swaps in host (more often 2 instead of 3 or 4) I find it more useful than having just one, since they act as communicating vessels together with main memory when performing `for sf in $(cat /proc/swaps | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'); do swapoff $sf && swapon $sf; done` which I sometimes would use as swaps _shake_.

Comment: What would that command do?

Comment: I use that as a substitute of `swapoff -a; swapon -a`, but I have forgotten why.

Comment: That command would try to get as most of swapped pages back to main memory.

Comment: I would accept this answer now, but first I would need you to remove your subjective judgment (the last paragraph) or at least demote it to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The
[fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)
format has these fields:

> 1. *device-spec* – The device name, label, UUID, or other means of specifying the partition or data source this entry refers to.
> 2. *mount-point* – Where the contents of the device may be accessed after mounting; for swap partitions or files, this is set to none.
> 3. *fs-type* – The type of file system to be mounted.
> 4. *options* – Options describing various other aspects of the file system, such as whether it is automatically mounted at boot, which
>    users may mount or access it, whether it may be written to or only
>    read from, its size, and so forth; the special option defaults refers
>    to a pre-determined set of options depending on the file system type.
> 5. *dump* – A number indicating whether and how often the file system should be backed up by the dump program; a zero indicates the file
>    system will never be automatically backed up.
> 6. *pass* – A number indicating the order in which the fsck program will check the devices for errors at boot time

When the *fs-type* is "swap", a priority can be specified via the `pri` parameter.
The default priority is negative (meaning none), numbered by the order in which
the swap device was added.
The first swap device added since boot has priority -1, the second added swap device
has priority -2.

Real assigned priorities have positive value, going from 0 to 32767.
Higher numbers indicate higher  priority.
If two or more devices have the same priority, and it is the highest priority
available, pages are allocated on a round-robin basis between them.

Reference: [swapon(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/swapon).